# how to do type safe money operation in java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm new in Java, and I try to make type-safe money operation with generics.
For example, there is a function add, I want to be sure that I can't add dollars to euros, and that if I add dollars I'll get only dollars.

In my snippet, I don't know how to convert from BigDecimal to T type.
Could you please help me with that, or maybe to propose another design.
Thanks in advance

```
package com.company;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Money extends BigDecimal{

            public Money(int val) {
                super(val);
            }
        }

        class Euro extends Money {
            public Euro(int val) {
                super(val);
            }

        }

        class Usd extends Money {
            public Usd(int val) {
                super(val);
            }
        }

        class Operation{
            public <T extends Money> T add(T a, T b){
                return (T) a.add(b);
            }
        }

        Operation operation = new Operation();
        Usd usdResult = operation.add(new Usd(5), new Usd(5));
        Euro euroResult = operation.add(new Euro(5), new Euro(5));
        System.out.println(usdResult);
        System.out.println(euroResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a money type. I recommend using [JSR 354](https://javamoney.github.io/). Note that searching for "Java money" returns this as a top-3 hit. (If the fact that money is the example here is merely a scenario for learning about generics, please describe that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would suggest [Composition over Inheritance], because `BigDecimal` methods return `BigDecimal` instances, not `Money`, so inheriting from it doesn't have much value. You'd have to write your own `add` method that returns a `Money` either way...

Next, to achieve type safety, I suggest making `Money` generic, and making the currency types unrelated to `Money`. Yes, they "are a kind of" `Money`, but it's not type safe that way. `Money.add` would return an instance of `Money`, not a `Euro`, so `Euro` can't inherit `Money.add`.

This is how it would look:

```
class Money<T extends Currency> {
    private BigDecimal value;

    public Money(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Money<T> add(Money<T> other) {
        return new Money<>(value.add(other.value));
    }

    // plus other operations...
}

interface Currency {}
final class Euro implements Currency { private Euro() {} }
final class Usd implements Currency { private Usd() {} }
```

Because generics are invariant, you can't add a `Money<Usd>` to a `Money<Euro>`.

Comment: For additional brevity you could make `Euro` and `Usd` into enums.